# Rotating pixel art while maintaining the same Pixel Count even if the image itself gets badly distorted

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find a way to take any Pixel art and rotate it fully 360 degrees without creating gaps, and without removing pixels at any point.
Even if this means the end result is significantly distorted. While this is being rendered it's not the rendering of it I care about, it's the individual pixels I care about I can't simply create new or delete existing pixels at different rotations. The total pixel count must remain the same (or at least as close as possible) at any angle.

[Heres a Gif of the problem](https://gyazo.com/4ef982c4377525fdba3b2987ea768c78)

The Left image is Not rotated, the Right is rotated 90 degrees these are fine.
The middle one is rotated like 85 or so degrees and you can see if I move back and forth, some pixels disappear while others are created, Specifically on the left/right sides of the middle image. You can see it just deletes those 2 edge pixels rather than moving them.

I need to find a way that solely MOVES the pixels, without overwriting any pixels, deleting, or creating.
Imagine them all being made from Physical Matter, I cannot Create nor Destroy them, I can only move them, I cannot put two pixels inside the same cell either all I can do is Move them.

Comment: First: it is not entirely clear what you want to achieve, so please explain in more details and with examples. Second: what did you tried so far, why didn't it worked...

Comment: Gave a better description alongside a GIF.

Well in that gif you can see one of the things i tried, Nearest sampling, i tried some other super simple methods like "removing all pixels" rotating all their positions relative to the center of the pixels, and placing the pixels back in rounding those positions to nearest cells, same issue though.

Comment: What you could do is: calculate for each vector from the center of rotation to the pixel coords, rotate the vector by the wanted amount and then length or shorten the vector to the nearest grid position and if two vectors would sit in the same, move the one further form the center of rotation to further away from the center

Comment: @Ackdari What if the area that's overlapping is completely surrounded by other pixels? i would have to push the pixel further out possible completely out of the image to the borders breaking the image? While i accept distortion i cant break the image, i only have 1 instance of it, rotating it needs to come back around to the same result :\

Comment: @Flater by "move" I'm referring to not creating nor destroying pixels because I don't care about visuals, I'm moving the Color data to another cell, rather than changing any of it.

Comment: Trying to think of another way to explain the problem :\

Comment: @Flater Yea it is a Grid, it's like a 2d Minecraft since I have a very similar concept for my game. Minecraft is a survival game, each "cell" is valuable, so rather than creating/destroying them, I need to just move the data inside the cells to another cell, while still resembling the original image. I understand why this issue happens in normal pixel art, but in my case, it should be possible to get around it, since I really don't care about the results, as long as it resembles the original image and it rotated and can do a full 360 and look like the original.

Comment: @Flater "cannot accurately accommodate a rotated set of elements"
Exactly, and that's why I'm here. I have NO interest in getting anything remotely Accurate. I need the same pixels, the same DATA., not the same image then rotated.
It doesn't need to accurately represent the same image, just needs to have the same underlying pixel data.
If I wanted accurate I would probably just go with Bilinear sampling or something and be on my way. But because i dont care what the result looks like, i just care that the Data remains the same. None of those methods work for me.

Comment: @Flater Think of them as Physical Particles that can only move in a grid like fashion.
And only 1 particle can fit inside each cell.
I need to find an algorithm or something that can determine new positions for these particles when i rotate.

Comment: @Flater oof I have only heard the same thing, that a grid cant represent a shape that doesn't align with a grid Yup... im very much aware of that xD

Im trying to explain to you that I simply want to MOVE the COLOR DATA inside each cell to places that can REASONABLY REPRODUCE the original image. I dont need it to be Accurate, but it cant be random. I need to simply find new places for the Color data inside each cell, but I Lack the ability to Create or Delete data.

I dont need it to look like the original image I just need it to resemble it using the simple rule: No Creating or Destroying

Comment: Also, the game Noita did it, so that proves it's possible. they have moving Rigidbodies that rotate that don't create or destroy pixels but maintain the rough shape.

Comment: @Flater The new answer that just came in by Ackdari should solve my problem.
So there you go, Do you now finally understand? Also, I was referring to Color Data, not pixels, I did when I talked about Noita though but that's another game unrelated to my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is one possible solution for your requirements.

1. convert your pixel to vector with the origen being the center of rotation (cor). To do that you do for each pixel `p = (x,y)` `v = p - cor`
2. Then rotate all vector by the given angle
3. determine for each vector the closets pixel position. Something like `p' = v + cor` and some rouding should do it.
4. If now two pixel would sit in the same position move one of them to a different position by some rule. If the so moved pixel then again shares a space with a different pixel move the other pixel by the same rule.
5. Do that until all pixel have their own position.

It might also be good to "remember" the original vector/pixel positions so that if you rotate for example 3 times by 30° you end up with a perfect 90° rotation.

And no I won't give example codes because I don't have any and I also don't think that there is any library that does this kind of operation.

Comment: Hmm, This sounds like it would work! Thanks!
Glad someone understood it haha wasn't sure if I was just going crazy or not.

Comment: @NuclearWolf Your requirement is just really odd, you might also want to think about the design of your game of you need to rotate a square grid by non "even" degrees (by even I mean in this context divisible by 90°). This might also be very tricky to implement.

Comment: Yeah haha, it's a very unique game its a lot like the game Noita, each "pixel" is a physically simulated sorta thing.

Gonna be a wild ride though developing some of the things i want todo haha.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, you cannot **not lose pixels** when you rotate by some arbitrary angle.

[image]

Imagine 3x3 square, all pixels black except the center one, which is white. Now rotate it 45 degrees. How would you draw your resuling square onto the grid? Given your rotation is not anti-alised at all.

[image]

Even if you use anti-aliasing, your best shot looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't care about what the result looks like, it's gonna be messy, and ugly.
Since this is being used in a game, where each individual Pixel is highly valuable to the player.
Deleting or adding them out of nowhere is not acceptable.
So in this case, it would be fine to not even visually rotate the pixels.
This case using Nearest Sampling with a 3x3 square at 45 degrees, it looks like the first image, it doesn't change, and that's fine for my use case.

Comment: @Flater
https://snipboard.io/McPHYB.jpg
This here is already fine, in Paint.NET using Nearest sampling, rotating this kind of image 45 degrees results in an identical image.
and that's fine for me, I don't care about what it looks like.
I just cant Create new Color Data or Remove Color Data I have to re-use the existing data and just move it around to try and create a rotated image.

Comment: @Flater
Even this is fine for me:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/425163801944391682/844939852784336916/unknown.png

It has the same Amount of data, just moved to new cells, 8 black pixels. Looks horrible and doesnt really look like the original image that much in this case, but thats fine. as long as the original data is intact, nothing added or removed.

Comment: @Flater Actually I would accept an image like that if I HAD to. however, that seems really really bad and should be a very worst case. Because all i care about, is it reasonably "RESEMBLES" the original shape, and has the same amount of data. i dont care what it looks like.

Comment: @Flater Think of it this way, I'm not displaying any pixels, there's no such thing as Pixels.
I have 8 particles in the shape of a square, and all each particle can do, is move 1 unit either UP, DOWN, LEFT, or RIGHT and I guess the diagonals as well.
And I need to rotate that. each Particle can only Move in a grid-like fashion.

Comment: @Flater i'm so baffled right now. I'm surprised at this point YOU don't understand actually.
I have been working with Pixel art for Yeeeaarrs now, I'm a Game Developer for over a decade now. I know what is and isn't Possible (atleast i like to think i do). and what you're thinking of is indeed impossible. But I think you don't understand what I'm trying to explain.
This is why I'm trying to explain it without using Pixels/Colors anymore.

Comment: @NuclearWolf if paint.net's Nearest Sampling is ok for you, why don't you just code it? I mean, there have to be many examples on how to do so.

Comment: It's not, I explained in another comment area that method fails as well, it works in this particular case though since at a 45-degree angle it remains 8 pixels. but at other angles, it fails. It's also the same algorithm I show in the gif.